# c++ : creating tuple & adding an element

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I have several objects of custom classes and I try to create a class which can store all my previous objects using `std::tuple`. Unfortunately I'm new to c++ tuples. Below is what I've done so far:

```
class Universe {

public : 
    std::tuple<Plain, Point, Rectangle> all_things;

    Universe() {
        this->all_things = std::make_tuple();
    };

    template <class T>
    void add( T obj ) {
        this->all_things.append(obj);
    }; 
}
```

This is the error I get (the same error I had when using an empty constructor):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::tuple<Plain, Point, Rectangle>::tuple()'
   18 |     Universe() {
```

Also I would like to know if there are any tuple methods for adding a thing. Sorry, I haven't found any useful info over the net yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you see implies that one of the members that the tuple contains is not default-constructible. In such case you must initialise the member tuple with appropriate arguments to use the non-default constructors of the members of the tuple.

> Also I would like to know if there any tuple method for adding a thing.

Nope. A tuple contains all of its members from the beginning of its lifetime until the end. There is no way to add or remove elements.